# Mongoose - Increment object counter when added to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out what the most efficient way of doing this, preferably in one query. If I have an array...

```
[
  {
    name: "Eric",
    priority: 1
  {
[
```

If I append another object using `$addToSet`, how can I increment the counter? For example, if I add `John`...

```
[
  {
    name: "Eric",
    priority: 1
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    priority: 2
  {
]
```

I was thinking of something like this...

```
let room = await Room.findOneAndUpdate(
  { room_id: data.room_id },
  { 
    $addToSet: { 
      guest_list: { 
        name: data.name
      } 
    },
    "guest_list.$.priority": guest_list.length
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

I know this doesn't work, but it would be nice if I can get the length of the array and use that in the `priority` attribute as so...

```
"guest_list.$.priority": guest_list.length
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly store array length if you can alway calculate it on the fly?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.4/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field.html

Comment: @user2814599 Well essentially what I want is to increment the `priority` after I add the data to the array all in one query. At the moment, I'm doing it using 2 separate queries.

Comment: @Bolboa did you try the `schema.pre('save', () => {})` hook? But you'd need to use `findById` instead but then you can't use `$addToSet` :(

Comment: I the main objective is to make one query only, I would prepare values for both `guest_list ` and `priority ` for the query. No need to use the handy `$addToSet` in that case. The `guest_list` with unique values could be prepared this way: `guest_list = [...new Set(data.map(data => data.name))]`